# Android build yields "compiler message file broken"

Tags: java, android, build, android-gradle-plugin, java-11

When building an Android project in a Docker container (`openjdk:11-jdk`) I receive the following error:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 8.302 secs.
AAPT2 aapt2-7.1.3-7984345-linux Daemon #0: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.1.3-7984345-linux Daemon #1: shutdown

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The details of stack trace are:

```
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.16, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.AssertionError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.clone(Symbol.java:288)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.binaryQualifier(Gen.java:248)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.visitIdent(Gen.java:2064)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2264)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genExpr(Gen.java:819)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.visitAssign(Gen.java:1806)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAssign.accept(JCTree.java:1894)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genExpr(Gen.java:819)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.visitExec(Gen.java:1594)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1468)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genDef(Gen.java:597)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genStat(Gen.java:632)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genStat(Gen.java:618)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genStats(Gen.java:669)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.visitBlock(Gen.java:1031)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:1036)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genDef(Gen.java:597)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genStat(Gen.java:632)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genMethod(Gen.java:903)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.visitMethodDef(Gen.java:866)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:866)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genDef(Gen.java:597)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Gen.genClass(Gen.java:2202)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.genCode(JavaCompiler.java:756)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1631)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.generate(JavaCompiler.java:1599)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:973)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.IncrementalCompileTask.call(IncrementalCompileTask.java:89)
...
```

I have tried using the same java version as is currently in my Android Studio, 11.0.12, and I receive the same error.

I have also tried running with `--debug` and `--full-stacktrace` but don't get any further information.

Is there a way to find out more about this error in the context of the project?